# qt crash internal-error: virtual memory exhausted: can't allocate 32768 bytes

Tags: c++, qt, debugging, memory-leaks, virtual

Using qt 4.8 on windows Application is crashing randomly and rarely once a day 
It is not breaking in attached debugger and not not showing any code also.. 
i checked debugger log which says

> ~"utils.c:1401: internal-error: virtual memory exhausted: can't allocate 32768 bytes.\nA problem internal to GDB has been detected,\nfurther debugging may prove unreliable.\nCreate a core file of GDB? "
>   ~"(y or n) [answered Y; input not from terminal]\n"
>   ~"utils.c:1401: internal-error: virtual memory exhausted: can't allocate 32768 bytes.\nA problem internal to GDB has been detected,\nfurther debugging may prove unreliable.\nCreate a core file of GDB? "
>   ~"(y or n) [answered Y; input not from terminal]\n"
>   25^error,msg="unknown error"

Comment: This hints to a memory leak.  Check the memory usage of the application over time and if there is a continuous increase, debug to find memory hogging.

Comment: Maybe application is running using old win32 api on Vista and newer system? As reported on Dcraw faq:

Ostensibly to stop memory leaks, Microsoft decided that programs using the old MS-DOS API, including anything compiled with DJGPP, shall be confined to 32MB of memory. This limitation can be removed by some combination of service packs and registry hacks, or you can compile dcraw to use the newer Win32 API. Thomas Nicely (of Pentium FDIV fame) has a page describing the problem and various workarounds.

http://www.cybercom.net/~dcoffin/dcraw/

Comment: I dont think so because the crash is happening very rarely.. once or twice in a day when application runs continously...complied with qtcreator for windows. it was working fine earlier

Comment: you have to run some tool to detect memory leaks. I think Qt Creator has some tool included for such purpose. In Linux version it is a Valgrind. Check this http://qt-project.org/wiki/Profiling-and-Memory-Checking-Tools

Comment: Have you tried to used Google Performance Tools to detect where  leak occurs ?https://code.google.com/p/gperftools/wiki/GooglePerformanceTools

Comment: here is similar topic: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1013372/1387438

Comment: What was changed between "working fine" and "crashing on a daily basis"?

Comment: You're hitting a debugger bug. The thing that crashes is the debugger. Run your application without the debugger and it should be fine.

Comment: Its not a debugger bug bcoz the app crash in release version also without debugger...

Comment: @stefaanv the changes between working fine and not fine is earlier also the application used to crash and I found the problem and fixed it. now it is notcrashing for that reason but for some other reason that too once a day after running 5-6 hours continuously.

Comment: In that case, get some analysis tools to help you (valgrind on linux, pclint...) and get more warnings from the compiler and solve them, because there seems to be more issues with your code.  Help from the compiler and analyzers is mostly a good thing because writing bugfree code is only possible for very simple code.